# How to type text in photos android?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-imageview, draw

Hi How to write text in photos? I searched in google but I couldn't find where to search and find. Please provide me tutorial or guide for this solution. Taking a picture from gallery or from drawable and writing text on photos.

So far, I selected an image from gallery and displayed in imageview. But I couldn't find how to write text on that photo. Please guide me to provide solution.

```
    public class GetImageActivity extends Activity {

    private static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 1;

    private String selectedImagePath;
    private ImageView img;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);

        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01))
                .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                        intent.setType("image/*");
                        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);
                    }
                });
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
                System.out.println("Image Path : " + selectedImagePath);
                img.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);
            }
        }
    }

    public String getPath(Uri uri) {
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can obtain Canvas from the Bitmap and draw directly on it.
Suppose you got image path, decoded it into the Bitmap object, then you can do following

```
Bimtap bitmap = loadBitmap(path);
Canvas c = new Canvas(bitmap);
c.drawText(text, x, y, paint)
```

Here's more detailed code
[Draw text on bitmap](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2013/08/draw-text-on-bitmap-using-canvasdrawtext.html)